# mongodb & php - How to use nested level condition in find()

Tags: php, mongodb, database, nosql

First of all, I am VERY new to Mongodb, so please bear with me. I have a mongodb collection that has data like below (in PHP array representation):

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 8974439e66777114648b47dc
        )

    [mechFamily] => X07_B22
    [mechName] => X07_B22_61
    [mechType] => Original
    [spans] => Array
        (
            [noOfSpans] => 5
            [span] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => solid
                            [clipShape] => rectangle
                            [id] => 2d8c1d2a6756323beca8e6e59823e3b
```

My requirement is that I need to pass condition to `find()` which will give me only those records where `noOfSpans`is 10.

I tried:

`$myCollection->find(array("spans.noOfSpans" => 10));`

But that does not return anything, I looked at the nest query sections in docs as well as SO, but the answers are pretty confusing. Can anyone tell me how to query this mongodb structure?

Comment: Can you post your mongo documents structure and expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fluent in PHP's syntax, so I'm going to translate your document into mongo shell syntax and then propose a query. Let me know if I did it wrong and I will try to correct it.

```
{
    "_id" : "8974439e66777114648b47dc",
    "mechFamily" : "X07_B22",
    "mechName" : "X07_B22_61",
    "mechType" : "Original",
    "spans" : {
        "noOfSpans" : 5,
        "span" : [
            {
                "type" : "solid",
                "clipShape" : "rectangle",
                "id" : "2d8c1d2a6756323beca8e6e59823e3b"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The query to match documents where `spans.noOfSpans` is 10 is

```
db.collection.find({ "spans.noOfSpans" : 10 })
```

which looks to be the same as your PHP query that you say isn't working. Is my document structure incorrect? What do you mean when you say the `find` isn't returning anything? It's returning a cursor with no results? How are you checking?